# How to disable react-navigation drawer in welcome and sign in screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

In those 2 screens when you swipe drawer appears while it should not be opened on those 2 screens. I am using react navigation. I tried this solution which I found on GitHub. But it's not working.

```
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
```

How can I solve this trouble?

Comment: Hi, could you resolve this?, i'm having the same issue

Comment: How did you stack up your navigations?
authswitch is the parent? appstack is nested in authswitch? drawer is inside appstack? You may want to stack them properly

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
  swipeEnabled: false
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and upon checking my drawer has nested stack within it and in the documentation you are required to do this to disable the drawers in some of your screen.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-drawer-has-a-stack-inside-of-it-and-you-want-to-lock-the-drawer-on-certain-screens